# How to get values from `Login.aspx` on the client side?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

How to get values from `Login.aspx` and `Auth.aspx` on the client side using JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you trying to use jQuery on the server side, or are you just trying to submit a login form?

Answer (score 1):

You are headed in the wrong direction. JQuery is for client-side actions. You need a server side language to handle posted values - such as PHP.

Comment: thanks, How to call .ashx service using JQuery from client side?

Comment: I created login.aspx with Userid and password fields, which are to be pass using Jquery in demo.ashx